# Node.js: Extract data from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, express

I'm fetching product details using an API which gives the response as a JSON object.

```
{
    "productBaseInfo": {
        "productIdentifier": {
            "productId": "EKTDDD23232zYHR94E4",
        },
        "productAttributes": {
            "title": "Nova KT 72BC 1 Electric Kettle",
            "imageUrls": {
                "400x400": "http://img5a.flixcart.com/image/electric-kettle/4/e/4/nova-kt-722-c-kt-722c-400x400-imadddh2fdvuzpxz.jpeg",
                "75x75": "http://img6a.flixcart.com/image/electric-kettle/4/e/4/nova-kt-722-c-kt-722c-75x75-imadddh2fdvuzpxz.jpeg",
            },
            "sellingPrice": {
                "amount": 599.0,
                "currency": "INR"
            },
            "productUrl": "http://dl.mykart.com/dl/nova-kt-722c-1-electric-kettle/p/itmdddf398rhhhz2?pid=EKTDDDEGXYHR94E4&affid=userid"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the productId, title in ProductAttributes, and all the image urls and productURL.
I tried

```
var productURL = JSON["productAttributes"].productUrl
```

But it returns an error productUrl not found error. Looking for suggestion on how to extract the data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`productAttributes` is inside `productBaseInfo`. So you need to access it like this

```
console.log(JSON.productBaseInfo.productAttributes.productUrl);
// http://dl.mykart.com/dl/nova-kt-722c-1-electric-kettle/p/itmdddf398rhhhz2?pid=EKTDDDEGXYHR94E4&affid=nikhilgeo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this out but I'm getting an error " TypeError: Cannot read property 'productAttribures' of undefined.

Comment: Can you show the actual code which you tried? I think you are getting it as a string.

Comment: Hey I got it right I forgot to convert the json object to javascript object. Now it works fine.. Thank you very much

Comment: In case of imageurls: To retrive it I used jsObject.productBaseInfo.productAttributes.imageUrls.400*400; but node.js shows SyntaxError:Unexpected token ILLEGAL error at 400*400. How could I get image link with out refering to 400*400

Comment: @NikhilGeorge `*` is not a valid character for an attribute name, so you should access it like this `jsObject.productBaseInfo.productAttributes.imageUrls["400*400"]`